# Get value of prefer-32bit flag from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have simple installation program which chose folder to install and registry hive based on Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem and ProcessorArchitecture of main exe file of installed application. E.g. if ProcessorArchitecture is MSIL and Windows is 64bit I know that application will be executed as 64bit and thus it should be installed in "C:\Program Files" and application should use 64bit view on windows registry.

But I have problem with assemblies compiled in .NET framework 4.5 with set build flag Prefer-32bit. Application like this will run on 64bit system as 32bit process and thus it should be stored in "Program Files (x86)" folder. However ProcessorArchitecture of this application will be still MSIL so my decision algorithm will fail. Is it possible to get Prefer-32bit flag from assembly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Module.GetPEKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.module.getpekind(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns [PortableExecutableKinds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.portableexecutablekinds(v=vs.110).aspx) flags that contain a Preferred32Bit value.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
Module manifest = assembly.ManifestModule;
PortableExecutableKinds kind;
ImageFileMachine platform;
manifest.GetPEKind(out kind, out platform);
if((kind & PortableExecutableKinds.Preferred32Bit) != 0)
{
    //is Prefer-32bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Application like this will run on 64bit system as 32bit process and
>   thus it should be stored in "Program Files (x86)" folder.

Note that AnyCPU executables will be run as whatever is requested & **POSSIBLE**.

It can be run as 32-bit or 64-bit, thus to say that one should be in one folder, or not, is a bit weird. Even if **preffered32bit** is enabled, it doesn't mean it will be run as 32-bit process.

If your 64-bit application launches your AnyCPU application, it will be run 64-bit process(as there's no other option - otherwise it would crash).

Some of the architectures don't even support 32-bit emulation(ARM processors), such that "**Prefer 32-bit**" won't do much.

**Unless there is crazy good reason,** I suggest you to keep things simple, and install `AnyCPU` assemblies to C:\Program Files (x86) folder. It will be more maintable & simpler to understand.

Ps, technically, AnyCPU assemblies are marked as `32bit` ones, if you use PEInspect or similiar program(you'll see they are marked 32-bit, **pedump**, as such, it would be correct to put them to ProgramFilesFolder directory).

The "AnyCPU" concept is implemented internally within the help of .NET framework.